# How do I make sure with JavaScript that when I click on the checkbox, the input field gets the number 0?

Tags: javascript, html, go, go-html-template

[This is the gohtml code containing the checkbox and the input fields with id="number"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5uPb.png)

How do I ensure with JavaScript that when the checkbox is clicked, all the input fields are automatically entered with the number 0?

[The problem is that the 0 is entered in the first field, but not in the other fields when I click on the checkbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey0zu.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I need more than that, but for answering I am assuming your checkbox has id=chkbox

what we can do is add an event listener to the checkbox

```
let checkbox = document.getElementById("chkbox");
let inp = document.getElementById("number");
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {

  if (this.checked) {
      inp.value = 0;
  }
});
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is that the 0 is entered in the first field, but not in the other fields when I click on the checkbox. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I added an image in my post.

Comment: @JustinS give each field an id. I am assuming you want each checkbox to make the respective input 0. Give each text field an id, and add event listener to each checkbox to make the input field 0.

Comment: But how do you do that in gohtml when you only work with an input field?